# Yacc Calculator Parenthesis and Exponent problems

Tags: calculator, yacc

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few hours now and I've finally decided to see if anyone could offer some input on this issue of mine.

I'm attempting to expand on a Yacc calculator that can do a variety of tasks. the two remaining ones are recognizing parenthesis as well as returning the exponent. I admit that I'm still very new to this process but as far as I can tell compared to many examples I find, I'm not doing anything horribly wrong so I'm hoping this is a fairly straight forward problem.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
%}
%token NUMBER

%%
command : expr {printf("Answer is: %d\n",$1);}
        ;


expr    : expr '-' term {$$=$1-$3;}
        | expr '+' term {$$=$1+$3;}
        | expr '*' term {$$=$1*$3;}
        | expr '/' term {$$=$1/$3;}
        | expr '%' term {$$=$1%$3;}
        | expr '^' term {$$=$1,$3;}
        | '(' term ')' term {$$=$2;}
        | term  {$$=$1;}
        ;

term    : factor        {$$=$1;}
        ;

factor  : NUMBER        {$$=$1;}

%%

main(){
    return yyparse();
}

int yylex(void){
    int character;
    while((character=getchar())==' ');
    if(isdigit(character)){
        ungetc(character,stdin);
        scanf("%d",&yylval);
        return(NUMBER);
    }
    if(character=='\n'){
        return(0);
    }
    return(character);
}

int yyerror(char * s){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

The calculator is fairly simple but I don't see my problem. The code compiles with no issues and the other functions work perfectly fine.

I'd appreciate any help at all!

EDIT/Addition

I accidentally used the wrong code I fixed it and I added updated code from advice provided by @rici.

This code is the new and properly function code.

```
%{
int yylex (void);
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
%}
%token NUMBER

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%precedence NEG
%right '^'

%%

command : expr {printf("Answer is: %d\n",$1);}
        ;


expr    : expr '-' term {$$=$1-$3;}
        | expr '+' term {$$=$1+$3;}
        | expr '*' term {$$=$1*$3;}
        | expr '/' term {$$=$1/$3;}
        | expr '%' term {$$=$1%$3;}
        | '-' term %prec NEG {$$=-$2;}
        | expr '^' term {$$=pow($1,$3);}
        | '(' expr ')'  {$$=$2;}
        | term  {$$=$1;}
        ;

term    : factor        {$$=$1;}
        ;

factor  : NUMBER        {$$=$1;}

%%

main(){
    return yyparse();
}

int yylex(void){
    int character;
    while((character=getchar())==' ');
    if(isdigit(character)){
        ungetc(character,stdin);
        scanf("%d",&yylval);
        return(NUMBER);
    }
    if(character=='\n'){
        return(0);
    }
    return(character);
}

int yyerror(char * s){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That program gives me a bunch of compiler warnings and a linker error. Did you leave out some declarations at the beginning?

Comment: I accidentally linked the wrong code. I was in a hurry when I made the question and didn't notice that one of the lines was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your issue with exponentiation is (and you don't describe the problem at all) except that you need to

```
#include <math.h>
```

if you're going to use `pow`. You also need to add `-lm` to your compilation command. Since you don't include the math header, the compiler will assume that `pow` takes `int` arguments and produces an `int` result, which is certainly not the case. Unless your compiler does something like automatically include math functions (which seems unlikely to me), that will cause the return value from `pow` to be meaningless. So that's a possible problem with `pow`.

The issue with parentheses seems a bit more clear. Your grammar says:

```
expr: ... | '(' term ')' term | ...
```

What that means is "One possible way of writing an `expr` is to write an open parenthesis, followed by a `term`, followed by a close parenthesis, followed by another `term`. (In other words, grammars are just what they seem to be. No magic or subtleties.)

Since `term` is just `factor` and `factor` is just `NUMBER`, a `term` can only be a number, and your parenthesis rule allows `expr` to be, for example,

```
( 42 ) 63
```

But it doesn't allow `(42)`, much less `(42+63)`. So that's unlikely to be what you wanted.

Your calculator also doesn't seem to have any operator precedence, so it will evaluate 2+4*3 as 18, not 14. Maybe you're OK with that, but it's a bit unconventional.

There's a series of example calculators in the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples). The example code itself is part of the bison distribution, and the manual text attempts to explain how the bison input is interpreted. The second example is a standard calculators with parentheses and exponentiation -- basically what you're trying to implement.

Comment: That manual you linked and your explanation were perfect. That manual is something I wish I had a few hours ago as it had nearly every piece of information I could've hoped for. I completely forgot about the operator precedence when was initially making this. It hadn't come up yet so I didn't notice. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I'm marking the question as 'answered' but I did have one minor question left. I decided to add the ability to handle negatives numbers as well and I've included the code above that I'll edit later. I included the `%precedence NEG' line at the top and wrote in the line for handling negative values but the program won't compile. It cites the aforementioned line as a syntax error even though every reference I found to it in the manual gives the impression that it's correct. I was hoping you might have some input on that.

Comment: @TeaDrinker: you might have a very old version of bison. Upgrading to the current version would be ideal, but you can use `%right NEG` as a temporary workaround.